# java service - spark communication

Tags: java, rest, apache-spark

I am pretty new to spark and am looking for some guidance :)

I have a java service which a acts as a backend for my application. I get some adhoc queries from UI and i figured out that some of these queries are taking lot of time. So, i decided to move to spark to get these tasks done. But i am stuck with how to establish communication with apache spark from java.

I saw other SO questions and it seems Spark Job Server from Ooyala solves my problem. I am just curious to know if there are any other options to solve my problem.

Comment: Hace a look to https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/java-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code provided to work on spark in java, you can write your code after the input taken in spark, since I've used here pre-built library of KMean clustering, you can take yours.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;

public final class Spark_KMeans {
private static class ParsePoint implements Function<String, Vector> {
private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

@Override
public Vector call(String line) {
String[] tok = SPACE.split(line);
double[] point = new double[tok.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tok.length; ++i) {
point[i] = Double.parseDouble(tok[i]);
}
return Vectors.dense(point);
}
}

public static void main(String[] args1) {

String[] args = { "/usr/spark_pack/spark_input", "3", "5" };

if (args.length < 3) {
System.err
.println("Usage: JavaKMeans <input_file> <k> <max_iterations> [<runs>]");
System.exit(1);
}
String inputFile = args[0];
int k = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
int iterations = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
int runs = 1;
if (args.length >= 4) {
runs = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
}

String sparkHome = "/usr/spark_pack/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/";
String sparkMasterUrl = "spark://master:7077";

String jarFile1 = "/usr/spark_pack/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar";
String jarFile2 = "/usr/spark_pack/spark_jar/spark_mlib.jar";

/*
* JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkMasterUrl,
* "Kshitij Stream Engine", new Duration(1000), sparkHome);
*/
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Log Analyzer SQL")
.setMaster(sparkMasterUrl).setSparkHome(sparkHome)
.setJars(new String[] { jarFile1, jarFile2 })
.setAppName("JavaKMeans");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

/*
* SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKMeans");
* JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
*/

JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(inputFile);

//****This portion is my algo part*************************
JavaRDD<Vector> points = lines.map(new ParsePoint());
KMeansModel model = KMeans.train(points.rdd(), k, iterations, runs,
KMeans.K_MEANS_PARALLEL());
System.out.println("Cluster centers:");
for (Vector center : model.clusterCenters()) {
System.out.println(" " + center);
}
double cost = model.computeCost(points.rdd());
System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
sc.stop();
}
}
```